# How do I get the Floating button to stay at bottom of the layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button, coordinator-layout

I'm using *coordinator layout*, recycler view and floating button. Somehow, the fab button doesn't stay at the bottom of the layout. I would like the button to stay at the bottom even in scrolling. What I do know, is that the fab button takes the bottom position of the last item in recycler view.

[image]

**list-activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            tools:listitem="@layout/activity_sample_05borangb_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Remove `android:scrollbars` or  `android:foregroundGravity` and have a try.

Comment: @KeLiuyue i tried it... but the button still hovering on the middle of the layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

**Try this :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: it still doesn't work... the button still showed on the bottom of the list instead of bottom of the layout

Answer (score 3):

You need not use android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout to achive this Relative layout is more than enough.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            tools:listitem="@layout/activity_sample_05borangb_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: since my recyclerView has two items... the floating button still show up at the bottom of the last item, instead layout bottom

Comment: I think the above mentioned answer should work for you Please try that and let me know the results.

Answer (score 2):

Make the following changes

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/container"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You need to specify a `layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity`

Comment: I have tried it... it doesn't work. The button still take the bottom of the recycler view instead of bottom of the page's layout.